# 100% is not equal to 100%?

Tags: html, css

When having two divs next to each other, with both a width set in percentages, 100% is just a bit too much, and causes the two divs to not be next to each other anymore.

99% then leaves a rather big gap between the two divs.

Is there a certain percentage at which the two divs do nicely fit on the page?

And what could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: With the css property `margin` maybe ? If a div has a margin 100% may not work.

Comment: Sometimes I have the feeling that this is due to the borders of the webbrowser. Do you have the same-result in full-screen mode?

Comment: It may not be possible to answer this without more context, preferably using an example.

Comment: It would be really weird if two elements of 100% width would fit into one parent that width is clearly 100% of itself. You meant 2 divs with 50% width? Because 2 elements can fit next to each other only if their widths adds up to =<100%. Ie. 50% + 50%, 10% + 30%. PS. http://jsbin.com/hojepinide/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And what could be the cause of this problem?

Most likely this is padding/border which adds up to element width according to default box model. To overcome it change [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property of the respective elements you want to fill 100% width:

```
.inline-blocks {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Remember to use vendor prefixes with box-sizing, it's still not supported very well without them.

Comment: @AmarSyla Vendor prefixes are not needed for box-sizing, only for very old firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using inline displaying, the new line between two separate nodes is included as whitespace. This results in the two elements wrapping despite their widths summing up to 100%.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.inl {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inl"></div>
  <div class="inl"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="inl"></div><div class="inl"></div>
</div>
```